# Using Kendo Mobile, How to prevent the view from scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, kendo-mobile

I have Kendo Mobile View which has three collapsible areas divs. I have an endless scrolling kendoMobileListView with in each with css overflow = auto. When I scroll it scrolls the whole view and not the listview within the div. The UI looks like this:

[image]

My markup for the view looks like:

```
    <!-- Contact Search View-->
<div id="employee-contact-search-view"
     data-role="view"
     data-model="klas.contactSearchViewModel"
     data-init="klas.contactSearchViewModel.initalizeContactSearch"
     data-layout="drawer-layout"
     data-title="Search Contacts">
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <input id="contactSearchBox" type="search" placeholder="Enter Contact Name to Find" class="contactSearchInput" />
    </div>
    <div id="contactSearchResultsArea" class="contact-search-results-area-hidden">
        <div class="search-collapose-buttom">
            Provider Contacts
        </div>
        <div class="collapose-contact-area collapose-contact-area-open">
            <div>
                <ul id="providerContactListView" data-role="listview"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-collapose-buttom">
            Vendors Contacts
        </div>
        <div class="collapose-contact-area collapose-contact-area-closed">
            <ul id="vendorContactListView" data-role="listview"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="search-collapose-buttom">
            Employees
        </div>
        <div class="collapose-contact-area collapose-contact-area-closed">
            <ul id="employeeContactListView" data-role="listview"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript to initialize the first endless scroll bar is:

```
      var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        pageSize: 20,
                        page: 1,
                        serverPaging: true,
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: klas.apiUrl + "/search/providers/",
                                dataType: "json"
                            },
                            parameterMap: function (options) {
                                debugger;
                                var parameters = {
                                    searchString: $('#contactSearchBox').val(),
                                    rowsPerPage: options.pageSize,
                                    row: options.take,
                                };

                                return parameters;
                            }
                        },
                        schema: {
                            data: function (data) {
                                return data.Data;

                            },
                            total: function (data) {
                                return data.Count;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    $("#providerContactListView").kendoMobileListView({
                        endlessScroll: true,
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        template: $("#contact-search-list-template").text(),
                        scrollTreshold: 10
                    });
```

The CSS for the Div that should allow the user to scroll the list view looks like:

```
.collapose-contact-area-open { 
display: block; 
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid gray;
height: 63vh;
margin-left:2px;
margin-right:2px;
border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

I want the view to be fixed and the multi views to scroll. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the view to [stretch](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/view#configuration-stretch)?

```
<div id="employee-contact-search-view"
   data-role="view"
   data-stretch="true" ...
```

The docs say:

> If set to true, the view will stretch its child contents to occupy the entire view, while disabling kinetic scrolling. Useful if the view contains an image or a map.

Comment: I used the "stretch" attribute and I wrapped my list view in a <div data-role="scroller"> and it worked for me. Thank you.